# Traverse through inner DOM element and replace inner DOM using angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to access the inner DOM by using only class names or html tags(as I am using library) and trying to replace with some tag. Tried using Element Ref with renderer but unable its unable to access inner HTML.

## someComponent.html

```
<div class="parent">  
    <a class="child">  
        <span>Some Text</span>  
    </a>  
</div>
```

## someComponent.ts

```
import { ElementRef, Renderer2, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';  
export class someComponent implements AfterViewChecked{  
constructor(private elem:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2){}  

ngAfterViewChecked() {
    var newContent = `<span>p</span>`;  
    let elements = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.parent a span');  
    this.renderer.setProperty(elements, 'innerHTML', newContent);  
}
```

*Error msg : Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null*

Answer (score 0):

> Your code is working in this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-renderer2-setproperty-innerhtml)

Your code seems to be working. Also, `var` should be avoided, you should replace it with `const` and `let`. Since you are setting the span innerHTML, do not repeat the `<span>` tag, unless you want to put a span inside.

```
import { ElementRef, Renderer2, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core'; 

export class someComponent implements AfterViewChecked {  
   constructor(private elem:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2) {}  

   ngAfterViewChecked() {
        const newContent = 'span content';  
        const element = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('.parent a span');  
        this.renderer.setProperty(element, 'innerHTML', newContent);  
   }
}
```

Comment: Look at the stackblitz, the only difference is ngAfterViewInit, but it works with ngAfterViewChecked too

Comment: No its not working for me, I'v put settimeout and its working now. What would be the reason, can you explain?